# Is this equation for mass defect correct?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I just want to know if this equation for the mass defect is correct

$$\Delta m = Z * m_p + Z * m_e + N* m_n - A
$$

where

- Z- Atomic number
- A- Mass number
- N- number of neutrons
- $m_p$- mass of the proton
- $m_n$- mass of the neutron
- $m_e$- mass of the electron

I came up with another formula also
$$ΔM=[(Z(m_p)+N(m_n))−(M)]$$
where $m$ is the observed mass

Which one is correct and what is the difference between both these equations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct formula for Mass Defect / Binding Energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104551/)

Comment: @Peaceman both are correct.

Comment: @AnubhavSrivastava-WASAYANSI The answer to your question depends on how (M) is defined. Please tell us what (M) means. Observed mass of what?

Comment: The first equation doesn't make sense in terms of units. The $-A$ term is unitless. BTW, please make more of an effort to use standard mathematical notation. The *'s and excessive parens make this a chore for other people to decode.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know if this equation for the mass defect is correct.
>
> $$\Delta m = Z * m_p + Z * m_e + N* m_n - A $$
>
> $A = $ mass number

No.
A is the mass of an $^A_Z X$ **atom**.

> I came up with another formula also
> $$ΔM=[(Z(m_p)+N(m_n))−(M)]$$
> where m is the observed mass.

This is correct if $(M)$ is the mass of an $^A_Z X$ **nucleus**.